# How to insert PHP row record into AJAX url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I possible to insert `update.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "` into AJAX url?
I'm trying to make async sql row updating via form. I don't have specific id, because id is called on click.

**JS**

```
  submit.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(validate()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'update.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "',
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function(data) {
                    if(data.success) {
                        id.val('');
                        cas.val('');
                        info.html('Message sent!').css('color', 'green').slideDown();
                    } else {
                        info.html('Could not send mail! Sorry!').css('color', 'red').slideDown();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**PHP** where update.php call is located

```
$sql3 = "
SELECT id, potnik_id, ura, naslov
FROM prevoznik 
ORDER BY HOUR(ura), MINUTE(ura) ASC;
";
$result = $conn->query($sql3);
$potnik = $row["potnik"];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //Spremenjena oblika datuma
        $date = date_create($row["ura"]);
        $ura_pobiranja = date_format($date,"H:i");
        echo "<div class=\"row list  divider-gray\">
                <div class=\"col-1 fs-09 fw-600\">" . $row["id"] . " </div>
                  <div class=\"col-3 flex-vcenter-items fw-600 fs-09\">" . $row["naslov"] . " </div>
                <div class=\"col-1 flex-vcenter-items fw-600 fs-09\">$ura_pobiranja</div>
            ";

        if ($row["naslov"] !== null) {
            echo " <div class=\"col-6 flex-vcenter-items fs-1\">Nastavi uro<form id='form' action='update.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "' method='POST'><input id='id' name='potnik' value='".$row["id"]."' type='hidden' /> <input id='cas' class=\"form-control fancy-border\" type=\"text\" name=\"posodobljeni_cas\"/><input id='submit' type='submit' value='Posodobi'>    <label id=\"info\"></label></form></div>";
            echo " </div>";
        }
        else {
            echo " </div>";
        }

    }
} else {
    echo "<div class=\"col flex-vcenter-items fw-100 fs-1\"><i class=\"far fa-frown-open pr-3\"></i>Nimaš še nobenih opravil
                                    </div>";
}
```

Comment: It would be best to insert the `$row['id']` value into your HTML so that your jQuery can read it. So jQuery can read it from the `action` or you can add `data-id='{$row['id']}'` someplace in your HTML. Then jQuery can ready the `.data("id")` from that.

Comment: @Twisty Could you please provide an example for HTML data atribute. I would still need to use javascript to insert selected id into HTML data atriubute ?

Comment: Unable to provide an example, but can make some suggestions. In the future, please provide a more complete and verifiable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will want to fix a lot of your HTML. You have many repeating ID attributes for various HTML elements. This will cause many JavaScript issues and is incorrect syntax for HTML.

```
  $html = ""
  $id = $row['id'];
  if ($row["naslov"] !== null) {
    $html .= "<div class='col-6 flex-vcenter-items fs-1'>\r\n";
    $html .= "\tNastavi uro\r\n";
    $html .= "\t<form id='form-$id' action='update.php?id=$id' method='POST' data-id='$id'>\r\n";
    $html .= "\t\t<input id='cas-$id' class='form-control fancy-border' type='text' name='posodobljeni_cas' />\r\n";
    $html .= "\t\t<input id='submit-$id' type='submit' value='Posodobi'>    <label id='info-$id'></label>\r\n";
    $html .= "\t</form>\r\n</div>\r\n";
    $html .= "</div>";
    echo $html;
  } else {
    echo " </div>";
  }
```

You can see a lot being done here. First we create a `$html` and `$id` variable to just make things easier. Now when we enter String data into the `$html` variable, if we're using `"` (double quote) for wrapping, we can just use `$id` directly in the string. We will also use `'` (single quote) for wrapping all the HTML Element attributes.

Try this for your jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("form[id|='form']").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var id = form.data("id");
    var cas = $("inptu[id|='cas']", form);
    var info = $("input[id|='info']", form);
    if(validate()) {
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: form.attr("action"),
       data: form.serialize(),
       dataType: "json"
     }).done(function(data) {
       if(data.success) {
         id.val('');
         cas.val('');
         info.html('Message sent!').css('color', 'green').slideDown();
       } else {
         info.html('Could not send mail! Sorry!').css('color', 'red').slideDown();
       }
     });
   }
 });
});
```

More Info on the selector: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/

Unable to test this as you have not provided a testing area. Hope it helps.

Comment: I suggest ditching all the `\t` and `\r\n`... as those are needless whitespace. Most all browser devtools pretty-format html when viewing elements anyhow ;) And in some cases, those whitespace chars will cause 2-pixel gaps depending on css/styles.

Comment: @IncredibleHat this is true yet I think Format is still important for HTML. Yes, most dev tools will format the HTML properly. Also if a little whitespace is causing CSS issues for you, you need to work more on your CSS.

Comment: Well, I don't consider the css-hack of `-2px` to be valid css ... When its an artifact of extra whitespace in certain browsers, then the cleanest solution is to remove the taint of such needless whitespace :) Plus, bytes man! Its extra bytes! Save the internet! lol

Comment: @IncredibleHat priorities and goals, what you said is true, cutting out unneeded whitespace will make the document smaller in size and will cause it to load faster. I'm doing my part then?? lol I also want to emphasize in my example code some basic standards where the original code was missing a lot of it. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the PHP $row['id']; variable to a local JS variable and append it to the URL as shown below -

```
submit.on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(validate()) {
                       var id=<?=$row['id'];?>; 
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",                                
                            url: 'update.php?id='+id,
                            data: form.serialize(),
                            dataType: "json"
                        }).done(function(data) {
                            if(data.success) {
                                id.val('');
                                cas.val('');
                                info.html('Message sent!').css('color', 'green').slideDown();
                            } else {
                                info.html('Could not send mail! Sorry!').css('color', 'red').slideDown();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This is ignoring update.php?id=" . $row["id"] . " that selected id at the end.

Comment: Is there any other way than assigning php variable to js variable id?

Comment: Javascript uses + to append text/strings, not '.'

Comment: I know that I can't use php syntax in javascript, but your answer is detected as react by my IDE and is rejected on running script.

Comment: Try this if you want to append the PHP directly to your URL -  url: 'update.php?id='+<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>,

Comment: Well, of course you can use PHP code within JS but you must escape it properly and the PHP must produce some output for you to use it meaningfully in your JS. Is your JS saved in a PHP file? If not, there is no way it will work.

Comment: Something must be wrong with this append, because it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: No need to append it if php is writing the html output. Just put it in the html: `url: 'update.php?id=<?=$row['id'];?>',` And if your IDE is too stupid to allow this, get a better IDE or handwrite your code ;)